# Spring MVC Controller method post and no post

Tags: spring-mvc

Edit: The below code actually does work. Hopefully this will still be useful as an example.

Is there a way to write two different controller methods for the same URL, with one handling normal requests, and one handling post requests? Like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/url")
public String requestWithoutData() {
  return "view";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/url", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String requestWithData(@ModelAttribute("foo") String foo) {
  System.out.println(foo);
  return "view";
}
```

When I run code similar to the above it always defaults to the requestWithoutData method. How can I get spring to differentiate between the two? I know I could just use one method with if statements but this way seems nicer if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand. Are you sending a POST request or any other type of request?

Comment: I'll be sending a post in some cases, and a simple url with no data in other cases. I have a form and a table on my page, but initially the user will only see the form. The form will send a post request to the same url and populate the table.

Comment: So `requestWithData` will handle the POST, `requestWithoutData` will handle everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can have two methods with same url but different RequestMethod. In first method you need to have method attribute.

```
@RequestMapping("/url",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String requestWithoutData() {
  return "view";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/url", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String requestWithData(@ModelAttribute("foo") String foo) {
  System.out.println(foo);
  return "view";
}
```

Comment: Turns out it works with or without labeling with RequestMethod.GET. The error was on my end, my apologies.